# Dependency Injection isn't injected on component inheritance - Angular 2.4

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

This is my base class:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-base-component',
    templateUrl: 'my-base-component.html',

})
export class BaseClass implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, AfterViewChecked {
    constructor(protected _serviceA: ServiceA,
    protected _serviceB: ServiceB,
    protected _serviceC: ServiceC,
    protected _serviceD: ServiceD) {
    }
}
```

and the child class:

```
export class DerivedClass extends BaseClass {
...logic DerivedClass...
}
```

Please notice that `DerivedClass` doesn't have a constructor and therefore is using the `BaseClass`'s one.

Since I upgraded from 2.0.1 to 2.4, I can no longer do that - _serviceA _serviceB etc.. aren't being injected (they are undefined).

I don't have a decorator above the `DerivedClass` since the only thing that changes is the logic inside the component.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41789601/angular-2-injection-not-work-in-inheritance/41791682#41791682

Comment: In that post there wasn't any relevant example, I therefore added one.